# Celery task not working in Django framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, redis, celery

I tried code to send_email 5 times to user as Asynchronous task using Celery and Redis Broker in Django Framework. My Celery server is working and it is responding to the celery cli interface even it is receiving task from Django but after that I am getting Error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vipin\appdata\local\programs\python\python3
es\billiard\pool.py", line 358, in workloop
    result = (True, prepare_result(fun(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\users\vipin\appdata\local\programs\python\python3
es\celery\app\trace.py", line 544, in _fast_trace_task
    tasks, accept, hostname = _loc
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0) 



task.py -
from celery.decorators import task
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
import time

@task(name="Sending_Emails")
def send_email(to_email,message):
    time1 = 1
    while(time1 != 5):
        print("Sending Email")
        email = EmailMessage('Checking Asynchronous Task', message+str(time1), to=[to_email])
        email.send()
        time.sleep(1)
        time1 += 1

views.py - 
print("sending for Queue")
send_email.delay(request.user.email,"Email sent : ")
print("sent for Queue")

settings.py - 
# CELERY STUFF
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/India'


celery.py - 
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ECartApplication.settings')
app = Celery('ECartApplication')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

I expect Email should be sent 5 times but getting error:

```
[tasks]
  . ECartApplication.celery.debug_task
  . Sending_Emails

[2019-05-19 12:41:27,695: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 3628 calling sel
f.run()
[2019-05-19 12:41:27,696: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 5748 calling sel
f.run()
[2019-05-19 12:41:28,560: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/
/
[2019-05-19 12:41:30,599: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2019-05-19 12:41:35,035: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2019-05-19 12:41:39,069: WARNING/MainProcess] c:\users\vipin\appdata\local\prog
rams\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:202: UserWarni
ng: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in produ
ction environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
[2019-05-19 12:41:39,070: INFO/MainProcess] celery@vipin-PC ready.
[2019-05-19 12:41:46,448: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: Sending_Emails[db10da
d4-a8ec-4ad2-98a6-60e8c3183dd1]
[2019-05-19 12:41:47,455: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: ValueErr
or('not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vipin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\billiard\pool.py", line 358, in workloop
    result = (True, prepare_result(fun(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\users\vipin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\celery\app\trace.py", line 544, in _fast_trace_task
    tasks, accept, hostname = _loc
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue when you running Python over Windows 7/10.

There are a workaround, you just need to use the module `eventlet` that you can install using `pip`:

> pip install eventlet

After that execute your worker with `-P eventlet` at the end of the command:

> celery -A MyWorker worker -l info -P eventlet

Comment: This is a bug when you are using Celery 4.x. In my case: 4.3.0 (rhubarb)

Comment: Do you have a link to the relevant issue? I would like to dig further.

Answer (score 0):

This command below also works on Windows 11:

```
celery -A core worker --pool=solo -l info
```

Answer (score -1):

```
celery -A your_app.celery worker --pool=solo -l info
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).